# Напечатать в порядке возрастания все цифры, которые не входят в десятичную запись этого числа

Tags: python

Напечатать в порядке возрастания все цифры, которые не входят в десятичную запись этого числа.
Не очень понимаю,как реализовать данную задачу.Нашел только код на паскале.Если кто может,помогите переписать на питон.

```
uses crt;
var 
  n:integer;
  m: set of byte;
begin
  readln(n);
  m:=;
  n:=abs(n);
  while n>0 do
  begin
    m:=m+;
    n:=n div 10;
  end;
  for n:=0 to 9 do
    if not(n in m) then write(n:3);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно?(и вопрос не о том коде который вы привели, а о задании)

Comment: Каким образом алгоритм реализовать?Какие функции использовать?

Comment: По алгоритму - получить все цифры числа, как это сделать - ну например остаток от деления на 10(как в вашем примере пытались это сделать, но там этого нет), дальше проверить каких именно цифр нет в вашем массиве и вывести их.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
print( ''.join(sorted(set('1234567890') - set(input("Введите число без запятых: "))) ) )
```

Конечно, если сможете преподавателю объяснить это однострочное коллективное решение ;-)

Comment: `list()` лишнее

Comment: @ПавелДурманов - Таки ДА!  ))

Comment: можно обойтись без цикла: `print(''.join(sorted(set('1234567890') - set(n))))`

Comment: @MaxU это да. Тогда вот решение-однострочник:
`print(''.join(sorted(set('1234567890') - set(input("Введите число без запятых: ")))))`
)))